# In SLDS, why the status bar of lightning datatable covers the date edit panel?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

When I use lightning inline editable data table component, the status bar would cover the edit panel.

[image]

I think it might is a SLDS bug.

Comment: did you try to add a CSS rule to augment the z-index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well.  I agree that I think it is a CSS issue on the SLDS side.

I'm using a lightning:datatable with inline editing, and I noticed that the footer bar div with the Cancel/Save buttons is using the 'slds-docked-form-footer' class, which sets the z-index at 8000.

Crawling up from the datepicker I noticed that the "table cell" contains a section element that has inline styling setting the z-index to 7002.  That section element also has a class of "slds-popover_edit", so my workaround solution was to put this into my lightning component's css file:

```
.THIS section.slds-popover_edit {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

Hope this helps, or that you've found a better solution by now.  I'm going to test my page to make sure this change didn't have any unintended consequences.